# What does "RC/CL/aj" stand for in an appointment letter?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I received an appointment letter. 
Below the signature of the director of human resource, there are some abbreviations, as follows:

> Signature
>
> Name
>
> Encls.
>
> c.c. Hd(COMP)
>        DoF
>
> RC/CL/aj

Specifically, what does this "RC/CL/aj" stand for? Does it mean the options for accepting/declining the offer?

Comment: On old-fashioned business correspondence, this is how they’d indicate who dictated it (capital initials) and who typed it (small initials.) I’d make this an answer but I don’t know what the third set of initials means!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Thanks. The capital initial is indeed the initial of the "Name".

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill perhaps two persons dictated and one typed?

Comment: @DarkCygnus team dictation!

Comment: Could it be the second set of initials is someone who reviewed/approved it?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill You should put that into an answer :D

Comment: @seventyeightist I wondered that, but having the last in lower case if so is a bit odd. This certainly isn't a standard abbreviation that I'm aware of.

Comment: As per Ernest's comment: https://penandthepad.com/how-8450891-indicate-typists-initials-letter.html

Comment: @berry120 Apparently not that odd, the link I posted earlier does state, *"Type the initials of the letter writer in capital letters, followed by a slash or colon. Add the typist’s initials in lowercase letters"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On old-fashioned business correspondence, this is how they’d indicate who dictated it (capital initials) and who typed it (small initials.) I am not sure what the middle set of initials mean: perhaps a second author, or a reviewer for compliance purposes. [Here](https://penandthepad.com/how-8450891-indicate-typists-initials-letter.html) is a bit of corroborating evidence for the general plan.